# What does `.` in Xpath mean?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I met an Xpath like this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('podcasts.opml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for node in tree.findall('.//outline'):
    pass
```

I know that `//`means `any matches`, but what does the `.` before `//` means? Does that mean `relative path`? But what is the `current path` in the codes? Is it the root path? Then could it be written as `///outline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what does the . before // means?

It means "the current node".

> But what is the **current path** in the codes? Is it the root path? Then could it be written as ///outline?

**Current path** is the node you're searching from. It's not necessary the root (but for `tree` in the above example it is).

Comment: No, "///" outline is incorrect, even though it appears logical. You want "//outline".

Answer (score 1):

> A location step of `.` is short for `self::node()`. This is particularly
>   useful in conjunction with `//.`  For example, the location path `.//para`
>   is short for `self::node()/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` and
>   so will select all para descendant elements of the context node.

Quoted from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/